# Check if editText of decimal number type is empty

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am confused for a long time about an issue. In an if statement I want to check that an editText with decimal input IS NOT empty. I found many answers to check if it IS empty but I want the opposite.

Here is my code:

```
if(r>20 && r<25){
    startActivity(new Intent(Knees.this, HandJoints.class));
} else {
    Toast fail=Toast.makeText(Knees.this, "Erased temperature/s not accepted\nTry again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    fail.show();
    elbow_r.setText("");
}               
break;
```

So in the first input statement I want to add an AND so as to prevent proceeding to the next activity in case that r field is empty. Besides this my application is running except the case I have no entry to that field.

Thank you in advance for reviewing my problem.

Comment: You do realize you can negate any conditional statement with the appropriate operator replacement (e.g. `!=` replaces `==`), or by preceding it with the NOT (`!`) operator?

Comment: My initial thoughts exactly. Java 101. Pardon, any programming language ever 101.

Comment: You don't need the last break line in this piece of code. Also try to fix the extra indent space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to check if a string is **not** empty:

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(eblow_r.getText())){
    //do something
}
```

I'm guessing `elbow_r` is the name of your `EditText`.

Simply adding a `!` in front of anything will make it **not** that, that's some Java basics.

Comment: I've tried all that but once I enter no value in the editText field it still crashes. I 've also tried !r.equals("") and !r.equals(".") and many other methods.

Comment: Is it a problem that the editText has a decimal input type?

Comment: Isn't it logical to first check if the edittext is empty and then to check whether it is >20 or whatever in the else branch (if it's not empty)? You're probably getting an error because r is null since the edittext is empty.

Answer (score 0):

This is my whole override method

```
 next1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            double r = Double.parseDouble(elbow_r.getText().toString());
            //startActivity(new Intent(Knees.this, HandJoints.class));
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button2HandJoints:
                if(r>20 && r<25 && !TextUtils.isEmpty(elbow_r.getText())){
                    startActivity(new Intent(Knees.this, HandJoints.class));
                }else {
                    Toast fail=Toast.makeText(Knees.this, "Erased temperature/s not accepted\n                     Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    fail.show();
                    elbow_r.setText("");}


                break;
            default:
                break;


        }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Vucko gave you an answer and if you take his piece of code you should accept his answer. You are using his idea and created your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(elbow_r.getText().toString())){
    double r = Double.parseDouble(elbow_r.getText().toString());
    if(r>20 && r<25){
        startActivity(new Intent(Knees.this, HandJoints.class)
    } else {
   Toast fail=Toast.makeText(Knees.this, "Erased temperature/s not accepted\n Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
   fail.show();
   elbow_r.setText("");
   }
}
```

and don't forget to add `android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"` in your edittext xml

Comment: Basically the same thing I wrote.